# Unexpected end of archive, while extracting a downloaded archive

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm developping a multithreaded download application, the download works fine unless when I download a zip file: the content is downloaded but when I try to extract it I get : unexpected end of archive, I'm using winrar. But the problem is relevant to the app itself, more precisely the multithreaded download, (when I use one thread I don't get this error).
Well here is the relevant part of code:

```
//Main thread Creates worker threads and starts them
for I := 1 to ThreadCount do
begin
  workerThreads[i]:=TWorkerThread.Create(URL,mapFile,PosBegin,size);
  PosBegin:= PosBegin + size;
end;

 //Code of worker thread:
HTTP.Request.Range := Format('%d-%d',[posBegin, posBegin + size -1]);
HTTP.Get(URL,ms);
data := MapViewOfFile(mapFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0 ,0, size);
copymemory(data,ms.memory,ms.size);
```

What's the problem in my code?
Thanks dor your replies.

Answer (score 4):

Your call to `MapViewOfFile()` is setting the `dwFileOffsetHigh` and `dwFileOffsetLow` parameters to 0, so every thread is writing its data to the same file offset 0, thus overwriting each other.  You need to set the view's file offset to `posBegin` instead.

Also, if you are not already doing so, make sure you have pre-allocated the file to the total file size being downloaded by all threads, and have created a file mapping of that same size.

Comment: Normally, when every thread is overwriting each other, I will get just a part of file, example if I use two threads, I'm gonna get just the half of the file, but I get all the content of the file, so I don't understand this point, and could you tell me how to change the offset of the file's view?, about the allocation, I created a local file (without setting its size) and then I created a map file and I set its file to filesize. Isn't that sufficient? If not, how can I possibly set the size of a local file (hFile)?

Comment: Remy is correct. Your problem is that all of your treads are writing data to the same location within your file. If you go and save this file on your hard disk and then make a byte by byte comparison to the file you are downloading you will see that your file only contains part of the desired data